# runing an android mobile application on android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Why when I download a source code from an android mobile application for reskin, and run it on eclipse or on android studio, it shows me a message saying that the code contains errors, knowing that the application Downloaded already works and published on google play..

Comment: What is the error? Please enclose a [MCVE] to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to change the package name to be the same as your project's package name. You most likely got the "R does not exist error" which is usually due to the incorrect package name being declared in the manifest (make sure to correct the package name in other files as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try to update android studio and reinstall the emulator packages, then try again. Sometimes its the issue with your downloaded files.